# Reporting services: grouping rows with color

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

I've got a table in SQL Server Reporting Services report. Several rows can have the same value in one of the columns and I'd like to mark such 'groups' of rows with alternating colors. How should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer.

http://kylefinley.net/archive/2006/07/06/226.aspx